# QT - How to know if the widget changed screens? Is there a signal?

Tags: qt, qt5, signals, multiple-monitors

I'm still a beginner at Qt (5.15.2) and I'm trying to implement a way to setMaximumWidth of the application MainWindow based on the current screen it's on.

For example: if the application is on screen 1 (1366x768) it should have maximumWidth of 1366, if it goes to screen 2 (1920x1080), then it should have maximumWidth of 1920, and the same logic applies to a N number of screens. Is there a signal that can help me with this? If there is not, is there a good way to simulate a screen change signal?

What I tried:

1. I've searched for a QScreen::screenChanged signal but I couldn't find one, so I assume it doesn't exist.
2. I've tried using QGuiApplication::primaryScreenChanged(), but it didn't work because it only works with primary screens, so when I merely change screens the signal doesn't get activated, only if I go to windows and change the primary screen to the one I'm currently on (which is not desirable).
3. I've also thought of using timeout signal that would activate a function that checks the current screen and sets the maximum width, it probably would work, but it doesn't seem like a good solution performance wise.

Edit: as for what would cause the screen change, it would be the user, either by dragging the window to another screen or using shortcut keys.

Comment: there is a resizeEvent(). you can specify a percentage of what the size should look like whenever the size is changed. you can broadcast this for all your widgets.

Comment: @BanAnn I think there is a possibility of resizeEvent causing an infinite loop, since setMaximumWidth can call resizeEvent again. Or is there another way?

Comment: an event -as the name suggests- only happens when you trigger it.if you have performance fears, you should say so from the start.

Comment: @BanAnn I have some consideration for performance as I stated on what I tried, but not much. My problem with using resizeEvent is because I can't think of a way to use it along setMaximumWidth devoid of the possibility of happening an infinite loop, since resizeEvent would call setMaximumWidth, and setMaximumWidth could call resizeEvent (which could, but not guaranteed, cause an infinite loop). Would this be appropriate? (I sincerely don't know) Or do you know a way to use it removing the infinite loop possibility? If yes, I believe this could be the answer.

Comment: *"I think there is a possibility of resizeEvent causing an infinite loop,"*, the easy way around that is to emit a signal with queued connection, or use `invokeMethod` with queued connection type, so the potentially infinitely recursive call will actually happen from event loop.

Comment: Reframing the problem slightly: what is it that triggers the screen change for the main window?  Is it a user action or... ?

Comment: @hyde Could you provide an example as an answer? Sadly I don't have enough knowledge of this method to make it.

Comment: @G.M. It would be the user. Either by dragging the mainwindow with the mouse or using shortcut to change from one screen to another (like Windows + Shift + Arrow).